# Awk output to read in a section

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, variable

I'm trying to output a variable & input to a new command:

```
jira.sh --action createIssue --project "BLAH" --type "Incident" --summary 
"THIS IS A TEST" --components "BLA" --priority "BLAH"| awk '{print $2}'
```

Gives me output `XY-1234` which is the ISSUE

i need to pass in `XY-1234` to the ISSUE section where the xxxx are... how can i go about passing this in `$0/1/2` show blanks and creating a variable with `name=$(awk '{print $2}')` and passing in $name is not working either:

```
jira.sh --action addAttachment --issue "xxxxx" --file "/var/log/blah.log"
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to get the jira.sh/awk output into a variable.

So how about this

```
JIRA=$(jira.sh --action createIssue \
               --project "BLAH" \
               --type "Incident" \
               --summary "THIS IS A TEST" \
               --components "BLA" \
               --priority "BLAH" | awk '{print $2}')

jira.sh --action addAttachment \
        --issue "$JIRA" \
        --file "/var/log/blah.log"
```